# Writing a batch file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script which contains PowerShell to get yesterday's date.

So far, I have managed to write the "get the date" part, which is as below:

```
powershell $date=Get-Date; $date=$date.AddDays(-1); $date.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
```

How can I pass the `$date` variable back into the batch script, so that I can use the `$date` variable to move files? What I am trying to achieve here is seen below:

```
move *%date%*.xml D:\Sample\
```

And I would like to accomplish this within a single batch script.

Comment: Why not write the entire script in Powershell so you don't have to pass a date back from it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to write a Batch Script (`.bat`) that uses Powershell to get the previous Date.

Below is what you can put in your `.bat` Script to get the value.

`powershell -Command (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`

You **do not** need to "pass back" the variable. Instead, you just make the output of the `powershell` call the information you want. Using your code you posted, there is no output. Using what is above, however, will be equivalent to "returning" the `$date` variable in your code.

Batch doesn't really have a simple way to capture the variable, however. There are two main ways to capture variables. You either use a `for` loop (this is kind of a hack), or to write the output to a file, then read that file into a variable.

**Method 1 - For Loop**
Here is the code to capture the output into variable named `v` (access with `%v%`).

```
for /f %d in (
  'powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString(\"yyyyMMdd\")"'
) do set "v=%d"
```

**Method 2 - File Output**
Here, we write the powershell output to a file, whose name is stored in the variable `tempFile`. Then, we read the file's content back into the variable named `v`. Finally, we delete the `tempFile`.

```
powershell.exe -Command (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd') > %tempFile%
set /p v=< %tempFile%
del %tempFile%
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice, forgot about that. I've updated the answer with the two main methods for capturing command output into variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the PowerShell command line as follows to get the value in a variable in your batch script:

```batch
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%d in (
  'powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString(\"yyyyMMdd\")"'
) do set "yesterday=%%d"

move *%yesterday%*.xml D:\Sample\
```

You shouldn't name the variable `%date%`, because that is a variable CMD automatically populates with the current date. See `help set`:

> %DATE% - expands to current date using same format as DATE command.

---

However, as @alroc suggested in the comments to your question, it would probably be simpler to just write the entire script in PowerShell:

```psh
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')
Move-Item "*$yesterday*.xml" 'D:\Sample'
```

Comment: Is the quoting right in `D:\Sample` in the last script?

Comment: @foxidrive It should be. Why?

Comment: The two terms on the the last line have different quoting.   Is one wrong?  Or both right?

Comment: @foxidrive PowerShell supports both single and double quotes. In double-quoted strings variables, escape sequences, subexpressions, etc. are expanded, in single-quoted strings they're not. This behavior is similar to other languages, like C#, Perl, Python, or bash. I normally use single quoted strings when they're supposed to remain unchanged like the path literal in the example above. The first argument to `Move-Item` is double-quoted because it contains a variable (`$yesterday`) that wouldn't be expanded in a single-quoted string.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you, I hadn't seen that mentioned and is useful info.  I'm likely to forget it too unfortunately - sleep is rare these days.  C, C#, Perl, Python, bash aren't in my vocabulary - I'm a bit of a dinosaur.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well do it in CMD.exe completly, although it is a little bit more complex...

```
:Get_Dates
set day=%DATE:~-10,2%
set month=%DATE:~-7,2%
set year=%DATE:~-4%

set TODAY=%year%-%month%-%day%

set /a tag-=1
if %day% LEQ 0 set /a monat-=1
if %month% LEQ 0 set /a jahr-=1 & set monat=12

if %day% GEQ 1 goto :done
rem day is in the previous month
if %month% EQU 1 set tag=31
if %month% EQU 3 set tag=31
if %month% EQU 4 set tag=30
if %month% EQU 5 set tag=31
if %month% EQU 6 set tag=30
if %month% EQU 7 set tag=31
if %month% EQU 8 set tag=31
if %month% EQU 9 set tag=30
if %month% EQU 10 set tag=31
if %month% EQU 11 set tag=30
if %month% EQU 12 set tag=31

if %month% NEQ 2 goto :done
rem februar so check year
set /a mod4=year % 4
set /a mod100=year % 100
set /a mod400=year % 400
set day=28
if %mod4% NEQ 0 goto :done
set day=29
if %mod100% NEQ 0 goto :done
set day=28
if %mod400% NEQ 0 goto :done
set day=29

:done
```